# Does LuaTeX access write18 differently from pdftex?

Tags: luatex, shell-escape

Im trying to make a speedup-option for gnuplottex using md5 checksums. This works like a charm for pdftex, but it fails for LuaTeX. The comparison of the checksums work, the difference occurs when

```
\immediate\write18{mv "\subfolder\testname.gnuplot" "\subfolder\figname.gnuplot"}
```

occurs. With pdftex the file gets overwritten correctly, with LuaTeX I get the message

```
mv: cannot move `gnuplottex\\Main-gnuplottex-test1.gnuplot' to `gnuplottex\\Main-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot': Permission denied
```

Is there maybe a difference in how Luatex and pdflatex work, concerning write18? On the other hand, as I am on Windows the reason may also be that I used

```
\def\subfolder{gnuplottex\@backslashchar}
```

which appears in the case of LuaTex as

```
mv: cannot move `gnuplottex\\Main-gnuplottex-test1.gnuplot' to `gnuplottex\\Main-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot': Permission denied
```

If this is the problem, how can I get rid of the double backslashes? I don't add another one as far as I know. Thanks in advance for your help and please forgive my poor description of the problem.

Comment: Fyi Lua comes with the function [``os.renam()``](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.rename) for that exact purpose. Makes it easy to work around escaping hell. And btw. there is a builtin [MD5 library](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/md5/md5-5/md5.html) as well.

Comment: FWIW, you can also look at the implementation of the [`filter`](https://github.com/adityam/filter) module of ConTeXt which provides similar functionality for ConTeXt. (Look at `t-filter.mkiv`, which is for LuaTeX).

Comment: I have just tried to reproduce the problem on my linux machine (with `\def\subfolder{test/}`) and it worked for both lualatex and pdflatex with `-shell-escape`. AFAIK, the `/` will also work on windows systems, and it does not need escaping. On the other hand, a backslash will *not* work on *nix systems (I tried it to check if latex makes auto-substitutions).

Comment: Possibly relevant here is the distribution you are using: TeX Live, MiKTeX, something else? (OS-specific stuff is no built in to TeX but rather depends to some extent on who builds the binaries.)

Comment: BTW, something odd is going on here anyway as `mv` is not a Windows command, so it really shouldn't work at all. You can use ``/`` as the path separator on Windows, not only within TeX programs but also at say the Command Prompt. Thus that is the way I would strongly recommend handling stuff within TeX.